# Corner Coordinates with high values from USGS (in NAD27)

Tags: gdalwarp, gdalinfo

I downloaded a GeoTIFF file from USGS (like: https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Maps/HistoricalTopo/GeoTIFF/AZ/AZ_Tatahatso%20Point_313664_1988_24000_geo.tif)

I'm trying to get the corner coordinates from it to gdal-warp another file to match.  gdlinfo gives this:

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   -6613.078, 4041570.234) (111d53'12.55"W, 36d30'24.17"N)
Lower Left  (   -6613.078, 4025161.834) (111d53'12.04"W, 36d21'31.84"N)
Upper Right (    6789.994, 4041570.234) (111d44'13.94"W, 36d30'24.17"N)
Lower Right (    6789.994, 4025161.834) (111d44'14.46"W, 36d21'31.83"N)
Center      (      88.458, 4033366.034) (111d48'43.25"W, 36d25'58.09"N)
Band 1 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
```

I don't understand the -6613.078 and 4041570.234 values.  What do those mean?

The whole gdalinfo output is:

```
Size is 6596, 8075
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["unnamed",
    BASEGEOGCRS["NAD27",
        DATUM["North American Datum 1927",
            ELLIPSOID["Clarke 1866",6378206.4,294.978698213898,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4267]],
    CONVERSION["Transverse Mercator",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-111.812999999999,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",1,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-6613.078324598224754,4041570.233840032946318)
Pixel Size = (2.032000000000000,-2.031999999999988)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=300
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=300
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=YCbCr JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
  JPEGTABLESMODE=3
  JPEG_QUALITY=65
  SOURCE_COLOR_SPACE=YCbCr
Warning 1: TIFFFetchNormalTag:Incorrect value for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored
Warning 1: TIFFFetchNormalTag:Incorrect value for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored
Warning 1: TIFFFetchNormalTag:Incorrect value for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored
Warning 1: TIFFFetchNormalTag:Incorrect value for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored
Warning 1: TIFFFetchNormalTag:Incorrect value for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored
Warning 1: TIFFFetchNormalTag:Incorrect value for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored
Warning 1: TIFFFetchNormalTag:Incorrect value for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored
Warning 1: TIFFFetchNormalTag:Incorrect value for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   -6613.078, 4041570.234) (111d53'12.55"W, 36d30'24.17"N)
Lower Left  (   -6613.078, 4025161.834) (111d53'12.04"W, 36d21'31.84"N)
Upper Right (    6789.994, 4041570.234) (111d44'13.94"W, 36d30'24.17"N)
Lower Right (    6789.994, 4025161.834) (111d44'14.46"W, 36d21'31.83"N)
Center      (      88.458, 4033366.034) (111d48'43.25"W, 36d25'58.09"N)
Band 1 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 3298x4038, 1649x2019, 825x1010, 413x505, 207x253, 104x127, 52x64
Band 2 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 3298x4038, 1649x2019, 825x1010, 413x505, 207x253, 104x127, 52x64
Band 3 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 3298x4038, 1649x2019, 825x1010, 413x505, 207x253, 104x127, 52x64
```

I want to extract the corresponding rectangle from another GeoTIFF in the same SRS by passing in a "-te" parameter.  The things I've tried have ended me up with a 15G file that I can't open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because  `PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-111.812999999999, ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],` points to -111.8129999 as origin. So longitude values westward would be negative and vise-versa.

The  `-6613.078 and 4041570.234 values` are metric X, Y for the same `(111d53'12.55"W, 36d30'24.17"N)`. Thus `111d53'12.55"W` is equal to `-111d53'12.55"` and also to  `6613.078 m west of the origin` or `6613.078 m`.

Comment: Ahhh.  I had no idea what that meant.  Thank you!